# Looping through a case statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to determine the best way to loop through a `case` statement until a user provides a certain input (in this case, `exit`).

So far, my code works with a `while` loop, but it seems a little redundant when I have `input = gets.chomp` over and over.

Here's a bit of abbreviated code:

```
input = gets.chomp

while input.downcase != 'exit'
  case input.downcase
    when 'help'
      puts "Available commands are..."
      input = gets.chomp

    #more when statements go here...

    else 
      puts "That is not a valid command. Type 'HELP' for available commands."
      input = gets.chomp
  end
end

puts "Goodbye!"
```

Comment: In future, consider waiting a little longer before selecting an answer.  A quick rush to judgement discourages other answers and is an annoyance to those still preparing answers.  I'm puzzled why you would prefer Tom's answer to Tobias', unless the later was not posted when you checkmarked, but of course that's your call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd write it like:

```
loop do

  input = gets.chomp.downcase

  case input
  when 'help'
    puts "Available commands are..."

    # more when statements go here...
  when 'exit'
    break

  else
    puts "That is not a valid command. Type 'HELP' for available commands."
  end

end

puts "Goodbye!"
```

A `loop` is designed for this sort of case, where you just want to loop cleanly, and then eventually break out on some condition.

For ultimate clarity in what the code is doing, I'd put the `exit` immediately after reading the input, instead of being embedded in the `case` statements. It's a minor thing, but is useful to remember if you're coding and others have to help maintain it:

```
loop do

  input = gets.chomp.downcase
  break if input == 'exit'

  case input
  when 'help'
    puts "Available commands are..."

    # more when statements go here...

  else
    puts "That is not a valid command. Type 'HELP' for available commands."
  end

end

puts "Goodbye!"
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!

Comment: I'm not so sure that moving `break` from within `case` to right after `gets` is a good idea.  If I'm quickly scanning code, I expect `case` to contain all the possibilities, and I don't think I'd miss any.  On the other hand, if I see `gets` and, out of the corner of my eye see `case`, I could miss `break` on the first pass.  It's a behavioral question.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you change the `while` to:

```
while (input = gets.chomp.downcase) != 'exit'
```

Note that this also means that instead of using `case input.downcase`, you can use `case input`, as it has already been made lowercase.

**edit**: my roots in C betray me...

As mentioned in the comments, this is not a particularly "ruby-esque" solution. It also causes a stack trace when `gets` returns `nil`. You might prefer to split it into two lines:

```
while (input = gets)
  input = input.chomp.downcase
  break if input == 'exit'

  case input

  # when statements

  else
    puts "That is not a valid command. Type 'HELP' for available commands."
  end
end
```

I separated the "exit" from the `case` criteria for a couple of reasons:

1. It was part of the loop logic in the question, so it's (arguably) more readable to keep it separate from the other cases.
2. I didn't realise that `break` behaves differently in Ruby `case` statements to other languages that I am more familiar with, so I didn't think it would do what you wanted.

You could equally well do this:

```
while (input = gets)
  case input.chomp.downcase
  when 'exit'
    break        

  # other when statements

  else
    puts "That is not a valid command. Type 'HELP' for available commands."
  end
end
```

**edit**: I am delighted to hear that like Perl, Ruby also has the `$_` variable, to which the value of `gets` will be assigned:

```
while gets
  case $_.chomp.downcase
  when 'exit'
    break        

  # other when statements

  else
    puts "That is not a valid command. Type 'HELP' for available commands."
  end
end
```

Comment: UGH. That's a very C or Perl-like way to write Ruby. Don't assign to a value in a conditional test.

Comment: @theTinMan my roots betray me. I welcome any suggested improvement.

Comment: Assign then test on separate lines. Processing speed isn't an issue when waiting for user input, and terse-code isn't rewarded, instead readability and maintainability are.

Comment: Better in two lines: `while (input = gets)` followed by `input = input.chomp.downcase`; otherwise EOF causes a stack trace when `gets` returns nil.

Comment: @theTinMan I disagree that an assignment within the condition is bad, at least in simple cases.  As an aside, I like the Ruby standard of enclosing the assignment in parentheses, as a sign of "I meant to do that".

Comment: I don't like assignment in tests because the `=` vs. the expected `==` is confusing when scanning for a bug, especially when the opposite case was meant (`!=`) but not used, or when it's mixed with normal tests without assignments. And, yes, wrapping the assignment in parenthesis helps denote that it was intentional.

Comment: Why put an explicit `if` for `'exit'` rather than incorporating it into the `case`?

Comment: It's useful for readability to put the exit on a separate line, but really is programming choice/style.

Comment: @pjs probably also a side-effect of me having more experience using C, where the `break` in a `case` statement wouldn't break the `while` loop, it would just prevent the other cases from being evaluated.

Comment: @theTinMan I'd make it the first `when` to emphasize its importance, but I wouldn't make a separate conditional for it.

Comment: `while gets ; break if "exit" == input = $_.chomp.downcase`

Comment: @Nakilon, that's not going to win any beauty contests.

Comment: @Nakilon I think it looks lovely. I've added it to my answer.

Comment: Keep in mind, that you probably would need to initialize some another variable instead of `$_` if you suppose to have a large logic inside `case`, if it is going to have nested `gets`s.

Answer (score 1):

You can even get rid of `input` by exiting the loop with `break` instead of checking the result in the while condition

```
while true
  case gets.chomp.downcase
    when 'exit'
      break
    when 'help'
      # stuff
    else
      # other stuff
  end
end
```

Comment: I think this is the way to do it.  Not only do you use `gets` but once, but your use of `case` avoids the need for a local variable.  I prefer `loop do` to `while true`.  The latter may be needed in other languages, but since Ruby provides the former, `while true` seems gimicky.  The former may be also be slightly more efficient (unless Ruby is smart enough to know that it doesn't need to repeatedly evaluate `true`). `case` is normally formatted without `when` and `else` indented, so `end` lines up properly.

Comment: Well, the indentation is certainly a matter of taste. I usually prefer the `when` and `else` part to be indented. True, it looks a bit weird with with the last `case`/`else`. Good point with the `loop do` statement. Didn't think of that.