# Ruby: while loop breaking unexpectedly

Tags: ruby, while-loop

I am a beginner at Ruby language, and I'm facing a problem for which I  fail to find the solution.

I will put a big block of code since I don't know where the error comes from...
The problem is that when I answer something else than "yes" or "no" to the question "Finished?", the program stops the while loop and goes to the next block of code. Instead of stopping it, it should ask me again to put "yes" or "no", until I put "yes" or "no".

Here is my code:

```
finished = "no"
#create a hash in which the values are lists of values, so I  can have keywords corresponding to authors, and lists of values corresponding to the lists of files created by each author
hash = Hash.new do |hsh, key|
    hsh[key] = []
end

while finished == "no"
    puts "What file would you like to implement?"
    file = gets.chomp
    time = Time.now
    puts "Who's the author?"
    author = gets.chomp

    if hash[author].include? file
        puts "There already is a file named \"#{file}\" corresponding to the author \"#{author}\"."
    #gives a value to the value-list of a key
    else hash[author].push(file)
    end

    puts "\nFinished? yes/no"
    finished = gets.chomp
    finished.downcase!
    puts ""

    #here, whenever i give the variable finished another value than "yes" or "no", it should ask again the user to put a value in the variable finished, until the value given is "yes" or "no"
    case finished
    when finished == ""
        finished = gets.chomp
        finished.downcase!
    when finished != "yes" && finished != "no" && finished != ""
        puts "Put \"yes\" or \"no\" please!"
        finished = gets.chomp
        finished.downcase!
    end

end
```

ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to show the correct version:

```
loop do # infinitely
  # some logic I did not looked much into

  # getting finished
  finished = gets.chomp.downcase

  case finished
  when "" then break "Empty string" # ???
  when "yes" then break "yes" # return it from loop
  when "no" then break "no" # return it from loop
  else
    puts "Put \"yes\" or \"no\" please!"
  end
end
```

Note the correct syntax of `case` as well as proper loop with an explicit termination.

Comment: Thank's for your answer, it helps alot. Anyway i found out several things about Ruby code that made myself understand that what I needed was a loop over a case statement, inside the loop that I already have.

I searched a bit and I found this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459495/looping-through-a-case-statement-in-ruby
The result: http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/189842rubycool.png

My program works well now, and it seems to me that the code can't be much more reduced.